# Why does multi-module project build generate empty jar files for submodules with stage?

Tags: playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I'm new to [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator) and am trying to create a Play project with a subproject relationship.

I use `activator` for local development and `sbt` on Heroku. It's sbt version 0.13.5.

When I type `sbt clean stage` from the `root` project's base directory, it calls the submodule and generates a jar file in the appropriate spot under `<parent_dir>/<sub_project_dir>/universal/stage/lib`.

The issue is that the jar file has the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file only with no other files inside, class files including.

When I build the submodule from the submodule's base directory using `activator clean stage` the jar file is created with all the correct class files inside.

Here is the content of the top-level project's `build.sbt` (minus library dependencies and repo resolvers):

```
import play.PlayScala

name := "perf-catalog-index"

version := "1.0"

lazy val index_worker=(project in file("index_worker")) settings (
  name:="perf-catalog-index-worker",
  mainClass:=Some("org.myorg.catalog.index.CatalogIndexWorker")
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")) enablePlugins(PlayScala) aggregate(index_worker)

aggregate in Global := true

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
```

And here is similar content for my sub project `index_worker`'s `build.sbt` file:

```
import play.PlayScala

name := "perf-catalog-index-worker"

version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")) enablePlugins(PlayScala)

// Setup the packager
packageArchetype.java_application

// Enable JAR export for staging
exportJars := true

val workerMainClass = Some("org.myorg.catalog.index.CatalogIndexWorker")

mainClass in (Compile, run) := workerMainClass

mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := workerMainClass

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
```

How can I get the `stage` command to generate a jar file for the sub project with the class files in it?

Comment: It's going to take a bit of time to figure out what's wrong, so would you mind publishing the project on github to investigate?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can publish the whole thing. This is part of my company's private github repo. I'll see what's possible though.

Comment: Just publish your own copy you used to reproduce the issue in a smaller and more controlled "environment" - you did create one before asking the question here, didn't you?

Comment: BTW, why do you use `sbt` **and** `activator` while `activator` alone is enough? Why do you bother yourself with `sbt`?!

Comment: No, I haven't created this problem in a contrived environment. I'll give that a try and then publish.

Comment: I use activator for my local work because I'm developing with the play framework. When publishing to heroku, we are using the standard sbt build pack there, which I'm assuming is using sbt to do it's work. I'm trying to make sure it behaves the same with both methods to ensure Heroku can build it correctly. Using activator at the parent level is also producing the same result as sbt anyway (empty jar files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My **guess** would be to change `index_worker` project declaration in the top-level `build.sbt` to have `enablePlugins PlayScala` explicitly:

```
lazy val index_worker = (project in file("index_worker")) settings (
  name := "perf-catalog-index-worker",
  mainClass := Some("org.myorg.catalog.index.CatalogIndexWorker")
) enablePlugins PlayScala
```

The reason for this is that you've got two standalone Play projects - `index_worker` and `root`. While `index_worker` is a complete Play project its entire `project` build definition is **not** picked up since only the top-level one is (that's how sbt works).

I can't figure out why `stage` is executed in the submodule whatsoever, though. *I may be mistaken.*

Comment: Your guess was correct. Enabling the PlayScala plugin from the parent build achieved the results I was looking for. The jar files that are generated now contain all the class files I would expect. Thank you for the time you took to look at this! Much appreciated.